# Creating a EventHandler class for buttons with different actions

Tags: java, event-handling

I have the following code at the moment:

```
public void initialiseButtons() {
    this.saveNewButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            savePatientData(actionEvent);
        }
    });
    this.clearFieldsButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            TextFieldHelpers.clearInputFields(dataInputFields);

        }
    });
    this.cancelNewPatientButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            clearWorkspace();
        }
    });
    this.saveChangesButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            savePatientData(actionEvent);
        }
    });
    this.deletePatientButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            deleteExistingPatient();
        }
    });
    this.deselectPatientButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            patientListView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        }
    });
    addNewButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            setupViewForEditingOrAddingPatientAction(1);
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see I have repeated the creation of a EventHandler numerous amount of times. Can someone guide me on how I can minimise this or is this the only way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Assuming that you have Java 8 available:

```
this.saveNewButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        savePatientData(actionEvent);
    }
});
```

Can become, using a lambda:

```
this.saveNewButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> savePatientData(actionEvent));
```

Or, for that particular event handler:

```
this.saveNewButton.setOnAction(this::savePatientData);
```

**Example of another EventHandler**

```
this.deletePatientButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        deleteExistingPatient();
    }
});
```

Can become:

```
this.deletePatientButton.setOnAction(event -> deleteExistingPatient());
```

### If you do not have Java 8 available:

Sorry, you're pretty much screwed. :(

Essentially, there is not that much code duplication as you might think, as each `EventHandler` is different.

The only way possible to solve it in this case would be to have all the buttons *use the same EventHandler* and perform a whole lot of checks such as:

```
if (event.getSource() == this.deletePatientButton) {
    ...
}
```

#### Side note:

If you are using JavaFX 8, you have the possibility to define an `onAction` in your FXML for your buttons, this will be associated with a method of that name in your controller.

See also http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-event-handling-examples/

Comment: Ah this is perfect, I should have specified Java 8 :)